# How do I reference another value in the current SASS map/dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, sass, scss-mixins

I have a SASS map of colors, and I want some of the colors to just reference another color from the map.

For example

```
$colors: (
     special-red: #a82523,
     red: special-red
)
```

However, when I run this, the value of `map-get($colors, red)` is literally `special-red`. I want the value to be `#a82523`.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not possible, to add a key when your map is not event initialized. You can assign the value to a variable $special-red: #a82523; and then assign that in the map

```
$special-red: #a82523;
$colors: (
     special-red: $special-red,
     red: $special-red
)
```

But if you really want to do that, then you can create a mixin and look up through that

```
$colors: (
    special-red: #009CDC,
    red: special-red
);

@mixin themeColor1($color) {
  $mapColor: map-get($colors, $color);
  @if map-has($mapColor) {
    color: map-get($colors, $mapColor)
  } @else {
    color: map-get($colors, $color)
  }
}

.my-class {
  @include themeColor1(red);
}

.my-class2 {
  color: map-get($colors, special-red);
}
```

But my recommendation is approach 1, set variables

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a kind of hacky way:

```
$colors: (
     background: #000,
     text: #fff,
     accent: #f00,
     link: accent,
);

a {
    color: map-get($colors, map-get($colors, link));
}
```

result:

```
a {
    color: #f00;
}
```